# Servicenow Export from Java code--- 401 error

Tags: servicenow

i am trying to read a url for JSON export from servicenow in java code but getting 401 authentication error please advise:

i'm using this link:

"https://servicenow.com/incident_list.do?JSONv2&sysparm_record_count=2"
-- Mocked up domain name..

Comment: 401 authentication error probably means that you aren't authenticating. ServiceNow requires basic auth to pull data.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a proxy (ie. Fiddler, BurpProxy, Runscope, nGrok) to see the HTTP request you are sending to ServiceNow from your code. The HTTP Request must contain an Authorization header (Basic Auth) as shown in sample below. You'll want to make sure the request that is being created and sent by your Java code has a correctly formatted and valid Authorization Header.

**Authorization: Basic {this should be your credentials Base 64 encoded}**

```
GET https://demo006.service-now.com/incident.do?JSONv2&sysparm_sys_id=d71f7935c0a8016700802b64c67c11c6 HTTP/1.1
Host: demo006.service-now.com
Authorization: Basic {this should be your credentials Base 64 encoded}
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Accept: */*
```